# Is it bad form to include an RSS namespace where it might not be needed?

Tags: xml, api, rss, xml-namespaces

I'm working on an API, one parameter that you can pass in adds a georss element to each item. If I don't include `"xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss'" as a [namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB0BC.png), the feed won't be valid. Is it considered bad form to add a namespace that won't be used sometimes?

Comment: Generally *No*, however your question might be easy to misread so I'm not perfectly sure I read you correctly. Care to elaborate? Maybe add a simplified example?

Comment: @hakre Sure, i'll add an image maybe that will help....

Comment: better add code than an image. but a good image is well, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad form, no... it's ok. However, this is also wasteful and something you may want to avoid.

Comment: If you don't use them but still declare them, you're using bytes that are not useful, which I call waste.